# shell script file search

Tags: shell, file-handling

I'm trying to go the path and remove the files starting `collectorlist*`, so I write the shell script like below., however -e option always give output not found. kindly suggest me.

**Script**

```
if [ -d "/abc" ] ; then
for c in `ls -1 "/abc/"`; do
  if [ -d "/abc/${c}" ] ; then
     if [ -d "/abc/${c}/dynatrace/agent/linux-x86-64/agent/conf/" ] ; then
        if [ -e "/bxp/${c}/dynatrace/agent/linux-x86-64/agent/conf/collectorlist* " ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found" ; then
          `ls -ltr "sat.txt"` > /users/home/abc/test.txt
            fi
         fi
   fi
 done
fi
```

Comment: i removed trailing space after the * , problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

1. There's a trailing space after the asterisk and before the closing double quote.
2. You are using an asterisk within double quotes; within double quotes wildcards like the asterisk are not evaluated but taken verbatim.
3. You are using backticks together with redirection.  This will execute the stuff within the backticks, replace the backtick-expression by the output of it and execute the resulting line.  So your `ls` command needs to give out the name of a command which then will be executed.  I guess you don't want that.  Just remove the backticks, you probably just want to execute `ls` and redirect its output into a file.
4. You try to find out if *any* file matching a pattern exists and use `[ -e pattern* ]` for this.  The `pattern*` evaluates to one or more file names or (of none exists) to the `pattern*` itself (unless you tweak your shell to behave differently).  The problem is the case of the many values.  These will make a problem within your `[ ... ]` expression.

Result:

```
if [ -d "/abc" ] ; then
  for c in $(ls -1 "/abc/"); do
    if [ -d "/abc/${c}/dynatrace/agent/linux-x86-64/agent/conf/" ] ; then
      if ls "/bxp/${c}/dynatrace/agent/linux-x86-64/agent/conf"/collectorlist* &> /dev/null; then
        echo "Found"
        ls -ltr "sat.txt" > /users/home/abc/test.txt
      else
        echo "Not Found"
      fi
    fi
  done
fi
```

Comment: Its just perfect. Thanks you so much